# "Ж" as a Mexican cattle brand

Tags: выбор-имени, фонетика, буквы

[image: Zhe]
[image: Zhe]

Could this be a Ж?

Two hundred years ago a young, literate Russian immigrant to Mexico claimed his cattle [brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestock_branding). Usually these were just Latin letters, with some flourish or packed together, or else a couple of lines and curves combined into a small fanciful figure. We have the above rude images, redrawn an unknown number of times, from a younger [record](http://library.ucsc.edu/sites/default/files/Cattle%20Brand%20Images_0.pdf) at the state capital.

This brand doesn't stand out much unless you think it looks like being a Ж and an inside joke by the only Russian speaker in the community. I know the Ж is not usually written quite this way, but it's hard for me to exclude the possibility that it be one.

Could Ж in some way relate to livestock, or to his immigrant status? Other suggested interpretations are more than welcome.

Comment: It's ж, no doubt. But in order to interpret the usage, you should know more about the person. It might be the first letter of his name or surname, his native city. That's the first thing which comes to mind.

Comment: This question is not about Russian, it's about whether or not some (unnamed) immigrant was using Ж or it's just a coindicendence.

Comment: His family name, his native town back in Russia, his loved girl name - whatever could be. Or nothing at all. He was searching for the "free" brand figure, one that was not taken by his neighbors already. The shape that both is easy to recognize and minimize and not taken yet. So, scanning from Cyrillic alphabet was probably an easy avenue. That said, "animals" in Russian is "Животные" and the very industry of growing cattle in USSR was called "Животноводство" (but I don't think the term existed before Russian Revolution )

Comment: Might be a [double H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestock_branding#/media/File:Holsteiner_Brandzeichen.svg)

Comment: And what planets are [these from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestock_branding#/media/File:Cattle_brands_in_MItchell_County,_TX_IMG_4547.JPG)?

Comment: According to the record, that brand belonged to Jose Antonio Bolcoff --originally [Осип Волков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rancho_Refugio). Until 1400s the Spanish [pronounced "J" as /ʒ/](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-J-pronounced-as-H-in-Spanish), so it's conceivable that the brand might have hinted at Жозе.

Comment: Osip is a south-east Russian/Ukrainian vulgar spelling of Biblical name  Josef/Iosiph. While in Spanish "J" is somehow spelled as "H" but for most European languages (French, English) it still sounds like "Ж" :-D

Comment: @shabunc i have to disagree. answers to this question are indeed details of Russian vocabulary and orthography (like the terms "Животноводство" and "Жозе́" offered above).

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for the lead, that's a good one:  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/el-sonido-de-la-j-de-jos%c3%a9-en-la-california-espa%c3%b1ola